# JPA not returning list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, netbeans

I am trying to return a list from a native query. getResultList() never returns. There are no exceptions thrown and the log also doesn't show anything. The same query in management studio executes in less than a second. What could be the issue?

```
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(" select * from [CB_L700_File_Item] c with(nolock)\n"
                + " where L700_File_No = ? and isnull(RejectionError,'') <> '' ", CB_L700_FileItem.class);
        query.setParameter(1, fileNo);
        List<CB_L700_FileItem> rejectedLineItems = new ArrayList<>();

        rejectedLineItems = query.getResultList();
```

The server output shows the query passed. but then nothing more

```
08:40:35,861 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22) Hibernate: BULK INSERT [dbo].[CB_L700_File_Item] FROM 'D:\FILES\SACCRA_BCP_\0040812160835138439467202.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='/|/', ROWTERMINATOR='~|~');

08:41:03,045 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22) Hibernate: {call sp_CB_L700_File_ApplyRules(?,?,?)}

08:44:34,797 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22) Hibernate: select cb_l700_fi0_.L700_File_Status_No as L1_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.L700_File_Status as L2_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.System_Date as System_D3_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.System_Org_No as System_O4_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.System_User_No as System_U5_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.Touch_Date as Touch_Da6_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.Touch_Org_No as Touch_Or7_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.Touch_User_No as Touch_Us8_17_ from CB_L700_File_Status cb_l700_fi0_ where cb_l700_fi0_.L700_File_Status=?

08:44:34,829 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22) Hibernate: select cb_l700_fi0_.L700_File_Status_No as L1_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.L700_File_Status as L2_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.System_Date as System_D3_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.System_Org_No as System_O4_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.System_User_No as System_U5_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.Touch_Date as Touch_Da6_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.Touch_Org_No as Touch_Or7_17_, cb_l700_fi0_.Touch_User_No as Touch_Us8_17_ from CB_L700_File_Status cb_l700_fi0_ where cb_l700_fi0_.L700_File_Status=?

08:44:35,239 INFO  [stdout] (default task-50) Hibernate: {call sp_CB_L700_SummaryReport(?)}

08:45:36,974 INFO  [stdout] (default task-50) Hibernate:  select * from [CB_L700_File_Item] c with(nolock)
08:45:36,977 INFO  [stdout] (default task-50)  where L700_File_No = ? and isnull(RejectionError,'') <> ''
```

Comment: Why dou you have '\n' in your query?

Comment: NetBeans adds that when you paste text into it for the line break.